# Illumina EPIC methylation analysis with meffil

Tags: r

I'm trying to run quality control on the new Illumina EPIC chip methylation data  with the meffil packages. 
I've used it with the Illumina 450k previously and then I've used the following command:

```
qc.parameters <- meffil.qc.parameters(beadnum.samples.threshold = 0.1,
                                      detectionp.samples.threshold = 0.1,
                                      detectionp.cpgs.threshold = 0.1,
                                      beadnum.cpgs.threshold = 0.1,
                                      sex.outlier.sd = 5,
                                      snp.concordance.threshold = 0.95,
                                      sample.genotype.concordance.threshold = 0.8)

qc.summary <- meffil.qc.summary(qc.objects, parameters = qc.parameters, genotypes=genotypes)
```

But for the 450K I've then had a genotype file. For the EPIC chip I just have the .idat files. Does anyone know how to call the genotypes from the EPIC chip?

Comment: Try [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/)?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that as well without any luck